# MissingMethodException when using WebRequestHandler's ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use the new System.Net.Http bits to build a simple HTTP client to talk to an HTTP-based API.  I installed the bits with Nuget (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20505.0).

I need to accept some self-signed certificates, so I'm trying to set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback property of the WebRequestHandler class.  Here's a two line test illustrating the problem I'm encountering:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanRunDummyTest() {
        var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
    }
```

but it throws:

```
CanRunDummyTest : FailedSystem.MissingMethodException : 
Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler.set_ServerCertificateValidationCallback(System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback)'
at AxlTests.RawAxlTests.CanRunDummyTest()
```

It seems that the Set property of the class is not implemented?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MissingMethodException`'s generally happen when compiling and executing against the same type which has undergone a *breaking ABI change* (forwards or backwards) ..

.. and I expect that is what is happening here.

Accoding to [WebRequestHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.servercertificatevalidationcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that property is *only* "supported in .NET 4.5", so using the .NET 4.0 version will go **kaboom!**

When building, be sure that .NET 4.0 (or applicable) is the target to (hopefully) get compile-time errors.

Comment: Aha... Yup, I neglected to mention that I was running VS 2010 and .NET 4.0.  Thanks for straightening me out ;-)

Comment: I have a NotImplementedException when trying to use this, but only on the Azure server. My project is set to .Net 4. How did you get round this in the end?